# Store jquery template data in each rendered dom node

Tags: jquery, templates, binding

I'm retrieving a list json data from the server which gets rendered using jquery template into a table of rows. For example:

```
<script id="entry_tmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr class="row_data" name="${id}>
        <td class="col_name">${name}</td>
        <td class="col_number">${number}</td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

And I render it in the standard way:

```
$("#entry_tmpl").tmpl(entries).appendTo(someNode);
```

Nothing special so far. Now note that I have some extra data in the data object aside from 'name' and 'number', and they are not rendered by the template. I want to be able to later on inside javascript, to access these properties. So I want to find a way to save the original data with each rendered note. So later on I can do something like this:

```
var elmentObj = $("#row_data[name='5']").prop('obj_data');
var other_data = elementObj['other_data'];
```

What is the best way to achieve something like this? I've searched around online and not able to find solutions that does what I'm trying to do.

Comment: it seems a loop in your question, you can capture it when its rendering into a variable, that saves it for later, but it looks like your trying that, but from an already populated table, which is AFTER the capture.  so what gives?

Might you be referring to much later, i.e. browser storage?   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Comment: sorry perhaps I did not explain it clearly. I already have the entire data stored in the variable 'entries', which shows inside my code, however, this is separate from the dom nodes. I have javascript code elsewhere which operates directly with the rendered nodes, I find it inconvenient to have to loop through my original 'entries' variable in order to locate the desired object. If I am able to store each element data inside the dom, my other code can simply get to the object quickly since my current code already have reference to the dom node. It's just more convenient this way.

Comment: it seems like after I render the nodes, I should do another pass to loop through my 'entries' variable and bind the data to the rendered nodes using jquery's .data() method. However, my question is, if there's a more efficient way to do this, perhaps while during tmpl() render, since it already is looping through each elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up just setting the data myself in a loop after I populate the table using jquery .data():

```
for (var i=0; i<entries.length; ++i) {
    var  e = entries[i];
    $(_.str.sprintf("#entry_tmpl .row_data[name='%s']", e.id)).data('tmpl_data', e);
}
```

This is not ideal since I was looking for a way to achieve this during template rendering so I don't have to an extra loop, but this does the job.